# Como alterar a cor de uma linha do DataGrid em C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Quando fosse selecionada uma linha do DataGrid e depois fosse clicado um botão, a cor da linha selecionada mudasse, uso o Visual Studio 2013 e é aplicação Wpf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este trecho de código altera a cor da *row* selecionada da *DataGrid* `myDataGrid` para vermelho.

```
int selectedIndex = myDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
//Guarda a Row selecionada
DataGridRow row = 
          myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
if(row == null)//A linha selecionada não está visivel
{
   object item = myDataGrid.Items[selectedIndex];
   myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);//Torna a linha selecionada visivel
   row = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
}
//Altera a cor para vermelho
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

**Nota:**
A propriedade *SelectionUnit* da `myDataGrid` tem de estar como ***FullRow***

Answer (score 3):

### Estilização condicional com WPF

Você também pode fazer validações no WPF, usando `datatriggers`.
Note que este trecho de código está situado no **Application.xaml**, dentro da tag `Application.Resources`

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tipo}" Value="Erro">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#ffb1b1" Offset="0.85"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tipo}" Value="Aviso">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#ffee86" Offset="0.85"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tipo}" Value="Info">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#c6deff" Offset="0.85"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tipo}" Value="Sucesso">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#c6ffc7" Offset="0.85"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Neste exemplo, os filtros aplicados foram para a coluna **Tipo**. A tag `value` está atribuída a por exemplo: caso a linha tenha na coluna tipo o valor *Erro*, então a linha ficará na cor que você atribuir.
Caso você não domine o WPF, você pode criar outros `setters` além deste que criei no exemplo, que se aplica para o Background da `row`, como por exemplo:

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px"/>
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
```

Para mais informações sobre este Styles/Templates, clique [aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24285/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-of-n)