# Como pintar uma célula de um DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Veja o código em [Como alterar a cor de uma linha do DataGrid em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38938/101)

Ele está pintando a linha inteira, quanto a isso não tem problema, o que acontece e que na hora que dou um *scroll* a linha pintada se desregula.

Exemplo: pintei a linha nº 1 ao rolar a DataGrid com *scroll* a linha não se mantém pintada. rolando a cor para outras linhas.

Comment: Há alguma relação entre a cor da célula e o valor que ela contém?

Comment: Não há nenhuma relação entre a cor da célula e o valor contido nela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema que você refere ao fazer *scroll* tem a ver com a forma como os elementos visuais da *DataGrid* são geridos.
Os objectos *DataGridRow, DataGridCell* etc, são criados e descartados consoante seja visíveis ou não.
Repare que o código da resposta a essa pergunta necessita que a linha esteja visível para poder obter uma referência à *DataGridRow*.

Para que o problema não surja, a informação da cor da célula tem que estar disponível sempre que a célula necessita ser recriada.

Para alterar a cor de fundo de uma célula, de forma estática, defina um *DataGrid.CellStyle*

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">  
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" /> 
    </Style> 
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Todas a células terão o fundo de cor vermelha.

Se quiser que apenas uma ou algumas células tenham a sua cor alterada, terá de guardar essa informação em algum lugar.
Normalmente a cor é função do valor da célula.
Outra forma é o valor da célula, neste caso uma classe, ter uma propriedade que indique a cor.

Exemplo em que a cor é definida na propriedade `CorDoFundo`:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CorDoFundo}" />
</Style>
```