# Alterar a cor de uma linha e tirar a seleção de um DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

tenho um método onde eu consigo alterar a cor de uma linha da minha DataGrid.

Segui através deste link: [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38930/como-alterar-a-cor-de-uma-linha-do-datagrid-em-c)

O problema está sendo como tirar a seleção de quando ele estiver pintado. Tipo, voltar para a cor original.

Tentei da seguinta maneira:

```
public void alterarCorLinhaSelecionada()
    {
        int selectedIndex = dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedIndex;
        //Guarda a Row selecionada
        DataGridRow row =
                  dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex) as DataGridRow;

        if (row == null)//A linha selecionada não está visivel
        {
            object item2 = dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.Items[selectedIndex];
            dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.ScrollIntoView(item2);//Torna a linha selecionada visivel
            row = dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
        }

        var bc = new BrushConverter();

        if (row.IsSelected)
            row.IsSelected = false;
        else
            row.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#169FDB");
    }
```

Nesse caso acontece o erro na linha onde ele pega a coluna 2

```
Object item = dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedItem;

        if (dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            cod = Convert.ToInt32((dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
            desc = (dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
            min = Convert.ToInt32((dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
            med = Convert.ToInt32((dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[4].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32((dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[5].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
        }

        p1 = new Modelos.PerfilVagaAtribuicoes();
        atribuicao = new Atribuicao();

        p1.Codigo = cod;
        p1.Descricao = desc;
        p1.PontuacaoMin = min;
        p1.PontuacaoMed = med;
        p1.PontuacaoMax = max;

        if (!_editList.Any(items => items.Codigo == p1.Codigo))
            _editList.Add(p1);
```

Erro:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: Provávelmente o dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells deve estar com Length = 0

Comment: Como assim Paulo? mas tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Faça deste modo.

```
if(dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells.Count() > 0)
cod = Convert.ToInt32((dataGridAtribuicaoVaga.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
```

Comment: Eu precisei colocar o "Count" ao invés de "Length" pq não encontrou...
E mesmo assim não deu, ele não consegue atribuir a cor dessa forma

Comment: Sim, porque voce nao selecionou nenhuma celula.

Comment: Eu seleciono com o Click do mouse sobre a linha Paulo, dai quando seleciono ele ocorre este erro

Comment: Tenta colocar  SelectedCells[0], eu atualizei a resposta

Comment: Não posso Paulo, pq estou recuperando o valor que está na coluna 2. que é o código. =/

Comment: voce seleciona TODAS as linhas ao clicar? se sim deveria funcionar. poderia postar o código na hora uqe está nesta linha? coloca um breakpoint e da um WHATCH neste objeto SelectedCells

Comment: Alterei Paulo..

Comment: Funciounou? como está? alterou o que?

Comment: Alterei o post ali em cima